# Unable to read file having # in directory name or in file name

Tags: php, file-handling

```
file_get_contents('http://localhost/project/ds_FWREF#1801\msg_1_ds_FW SYSREF#180133.json');
```

this returns below error

> [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found.

**Note**, the file exists in that particular location but, I'm unable to access due to a `#` in file name and dir name.

Comment: I highly recommend reading [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and more specifically the "Spelling, grammar and formatting" section. I've corrected this post, and fixed some of the common mistakes, but on future posts reading this article would go a long way to making high quality posts for future visitors.

Comment: XY Problem, don't use # for filenames, you should be avoiding spaces too.

Comment: Remember that's not a file system path—it's a URL.

Comment: @FrankerZ Thanks, i will take care of these errors in future posts.

Answer (score 1):

`#` is a special character in [URLs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL). It marks the beginning of the fragment.

In order to use its literal value in an URL it has to be properly [URL-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

Pass the file name to function [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) to produce the correct URL for it. It takes care of all characters that are [special in URLs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding_reserved_characters) (`/`, `&`, `=`, `#`, `?`, `%`, etc.)

```
$filename = 'ds_FWREF#1801\msg_1_ds_FW SYSREF#180133.json';

$content = file_get_contents('http://localhost/project/'.urlencode($filename));
```